# Which FOSS, Gratis, SaaS software to create digitally signed, English invoices and receipts will you recommend?

Tags: gratis, open-source, email, saas, accounting

I need a software to create digitally signed *deal documents* such as invoices and receipts, which is:

- In English
- SaaS
- FOSS (thus communally maintained and supervised - with no customer service)
- Gratis
- Communicates with an email server to send deal documents to customers from the software's own email server
- Allows easy manual backuping of all deal documents already created

I could add that I grasp such software as "apolitical" in the sense that it isn't associated with the taxation authority of any particular state or country; rather, it allows humans anywhere in the world to do global, free and easy bookkeeping.

Which such software will you recommend?

My prior research brought [invoiceninja.com](https://invoiceninja.com) but they don't have digital signage service (confirmed with their customer service on 29/06/20).